# Problema al generar consulta Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código

```
            if ($conexion->connect_error) {
                die("Conexión fallida: " . $conexion->connect_error);
            }else{
                $sql = "CREATE TABLE temporal (
                            numero_abonado varchar(100),
                            DESC_MERCADO_PLAN varchar(100) ,
                            DESC_FAMILIA_PLAN varchar(100) ,
                            DESC_PLAN varchar(100) ,
                            CARGO_FIJO_LINEA varchar(100),
                            DESC_PLAN_ANTERIOR VARCHAR(100) ,
                            CARGO_FIJO_PLAN_ANTERIOR varchar(100),
                            FECHA_ACT_CONT varchar(100) ,
                            DESC_CORTA_PLAN varchar(100) ,
                            rut varchar(100) ,
                            ciclo varchar(100) ,
                            inar varchar(100)                           
                            )";
                if ($conexion->query($sql) === true) {
                    $numero="";
                    foreach ($numeros as &$numero) {
                        //echo "$numero <br>";  
                        $sql = "select * from parque where numero_abonado ='$numero'";
                        if($conexion->query($sql) === true){        
                        //se guardo correctamente                               
                        }else{
                            die("Error al buscar datos abonados: " . $conexion->error);                             
                        }                           
                    }                           
                }else{
                    die("Error al crear tabla temporal: " . $conexion->error);                  
                }           
            }
```

Pero al querer buscar registros con el arreglo siempre se va por el else, es decir, muestra el mensaje "Error al buscar datos abonados: " en que estoy fallando, necesito de sus conocimientos

Saludos,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque `mysqli->query` cuando se lo usa con una sentencia `SELECT` retorna un objecto y no un booleano como cuando se lo usa para una sentencia `CREATE`, si cambias tu `IF` para que compare con un valor booleano `FALSE` este debería comportarse como esperas:

```php
if($conexion->query($sql) !== false){        
    //se guardo correctamente                               
}else{
    die("Error al buscar datos abonados: " . $conexion->error);                             
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Vlady, error corregido

Comment: la idea era cargar la informacion a la tabla temporal, lo que encuentre en cada iteracion del foreach, pero gracias nuevamente Vlady